# Lines of code automatically added without warning/consent

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

**edited tags to reflect the cause of the problem

I've been working with Node.js for about 3 months give or take, and today I was working on a project when I suddenly got an import error on the client side, even though I hadn't touched any code there since I last ran the program. In fact, the only changes I had made were on the server side, and it was just some minor refactoring that didn't have anything to do with the imports. After frantically trying to find what I'd done, I scrolled up to see this line in server/index.js:

```
const { default: socket } = require('../client/src/socket.js');
```

I didn't write this line. It had been added without me asking or even noticing that it was there. I'm pretty sure that I hadn't clicked on any formatting tooltips, and it seemed to appear out of nowhere and was the cause of the break.

This isn't the first time that this has happened to me. I have noticed that at sporadic moments, code is added to my projects that I never asked for. So I have some questions:

- Is this a feature of Node, and if so what triggers it?
- As I'm using VScode, is it rather the IDE that's doing this?
- How do I stop whatever's causing this from trying, and failing, to be helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a feature of nodejs.  It never modifies your code unless you write and run your own code to modify code.  Lots of IDEs have all sorts of features for modifying code so that would be my first guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely VSCode's built-in [auto-imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_auto-imports). You've probably typed `socket` and selected an auto-suggestion which contained *Auto import from "../client/src/socket.js"*

You can disable it with the setting `"javascript.suggest.autoImports": false`.

Additionally, if you're using Git for version control, try using `git add -p` (`-p` for [patch](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/staging-commits-with-git-add-patch-1eb18849aedb)) to stage your changes bit by bit instead of the entire file. This way you can review your changes in slices and you'll probably catch things like this.

Comment: This seems like the plausible answer - I've disabled it now. I can see how a feature like that could have use cases, but when enabled by default it has the potential to trip up a VS code noob like me. Thanks for the descriptive answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a feature of Node but, Some of the VSCode extensions possess capabilities of auto import. Maybe one of your extension has added that line. To prevent it disable your JavaScript autocomplete, linter extensions.